# openapi generator maven plugin : Polymorphism support

Tags: maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I have written YAML files with polymorphism syntax but i get a nullpointer error whenever maven plugin parses a definition with polymorphism schema.

Does "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" supports polymorphic YAML files to generate java stubs?

An example of polymorphis definition :

```
IRFloatSwapLegDO:
    title: IRFloatSwapLegDO
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/IRSwapLegDO'
      - type: object
        properties:
          amortizationSchedule:
            $ref: '#/definitions/AmortizationScheduleDO'
          compoundingSchedule:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CompoundingScheduleDO'
          couponSchedule:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CouponScheduleDO'
          currency:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CurrencyDO'
          dayCountConvention:
            type: string
          fixInArrears:
            type: boolean
          fixingMultiplier:
            type: number
            format: double
          fixingSchedule:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CompoundingScheduleDO'
          irSwapLegType:
            type: string
            enum:
              - IRFixedSwapLeg
              - IRFloatSwapLeg
          irUnderlying:
            $ref: '#/definitions/IRUnderlyingDO'
          legID:
            type: string
          notional:
            type: number
            format: double
          notionalExchange:
            $ref: '#/definitions/NotionalExchangeDO'
          overriddenFixings:
            $ref: '#/definitions/CouponScheduleDO'
          payAtStart:
            type: boolean
          schedule:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ScheduleDO'
        title: IRFloatSwapLegDO
```

Below is the exception which i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.OpenAPIDeserializer.getObject(OpenAPIDeserializer.java:730)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.util.OpenAPIDeserializer.getSchema(OpenAPIDeserializer.java:1957)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.ResolverCache.loadRef(ResolverCache.java:147)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefToExternalSchema(ExternalRefProcessor.java:48)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefSchema(ExternalRefProcessor.java:644)
        at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefToExternalSchema(ExternalRefProcessor.java:115)
```

Comment: Please try the latest snapshot version (4.0.0-SNAPSHOT) which should have better support for polymorphism. If there's still an issue, please open an issue via github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new with a spec to reproduce the issue